# Disable/Enable a form content

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to enable/disable a the content of a form like a fieldset in html? I tried to change the property <strike>"enable"</strike> "editable" of the form but it not works

Comment: `SimpleForm` does not have `enable` property.

Comment: You can try to bind enable properties of all the form elements to a single path in a modal, say my form has an Input field -

var oInput = new sap.m.Input ({enable: {oEnableModel>/enable}});
Also, the oEnableModel in Component.js - 
var oEnableModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({enable: true}); 
this.setModel(oEnableModel,'oEnableModel');
On click of button you can set the enable property to false and all field elements will be disabled.

Comment: @Dopedev sorry, "editable"

Comment: @Rahul I do that but if I have a form with a great number of fields it becomes difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code is enough to disable all the fields in `SimpleForm`.

```
onAfterRendering: function(){ 
     var formId = this.getView().byId("SimpleForm").getId();
     $("#"+ formId +" *").css({"pointer-events": "none"});
}
```

See it in action [here](https://jsbin.com/ripopub/edit?html,js,output).

Update:

> The setting of the `editable` property has no influence on the editable functionality of the form's content.

`editable` property does do to the form as the name suggest. In fact, it's confusing.

It sets the same line-height for the `Label` as that of fields like `Input`,`Select`, `ComobBox` etc. when `true` (means when your form is in editable mode). If you set it to `false`, `Label` and corresponding field will look misaligned.